# Mangled fonts in ubuntu 15.10 (mate) and set system-wide font path

Tags: fonts, 15.10, mate

I recently installed ubuntu 15.10 and I use mate desktop. When I try to open emacs from a remote machine, I get:

```
$emacs file.txt
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*--*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
[liviu@crystal module_test]$ emacs benzene.xyz 
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*--*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
```

and my fonts are completely mangled and I cannot see what's in the file. I read somewhere that this is because the newer ubuntu does not have those fonts and I followed the advise I found [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/error-message-regarding-fonts-in-grace-943919/) and installed the necessary fonts. I think one only needs to install `xfonts-75dpi xfonts-100dpi`. To set the font path, I use, as suggested,

```
xset +fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/
```

So, I have two questions. One is if this can be done easier, and second, how to set the font path permanently system wide.